# Show currentTime from wavesurfer.js triggers too many re-renders in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I'm using this `wavesurfer.js` package with React for display wave form of audio. I want to display the current elapsed time using this `getCurrentTime()` method in their [docs](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html) and answer here on [github](https://github.com/wavesurfer-js/wavesurfer.js/issues/753#issuecomment-229721073).

I got the elapsed time in seconds and update my React state to display it. However, it updates quite frequently, more than 10 times per second which trigger my component to re-render multiple times. I wonder if there is a way to make it only trigger state changes on each seconds pass?

```
export function Component(){
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0)
    const wavesurferRef = useRef<any>(null)


    useEffect(()=>{
        if (wavesurferRef.current){
            wavesurferRef.current.on('audioprocess', function () {

                //ISSUE: THIS MAKE COMPONENT RE-RENDERING TOO MANY TIME
                setCurrentTime(wavesurferRef.current.getCurrentTime())
            })
        }
    },[])
    

    return(
        <div ref={wavesurferRef}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest you `useRef` with a DOM node and something like [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to update the text. Here's a minimal, verifiable example. <kbd>Run</kbd> the program below and notice a render only happens when you click the button and update the state. The timestamp is updated using animation instead of state transition -

```js
const mockWavesurfer = { offset: Date.now(), getCurrentTime() { return Date.now() - this.offset } }

function useAnimationFrame(callback) {
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      let frame
      function onFrame(frameId) {
        callback(frameId)
        frame = requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
      }
      frame = requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
      return () => { window.cancelAnimationFrame(frame) }
    },
    [callback]
  )
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const wavesurferRef = React.useRef(mockWavesurfer)
  const dateRef = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() => console.log("render", count), [count])
  useAnimationFrame(() => {
    dateRef.current.textContent = wavesurferRef.current.getCurrentTime()
  })
  return <div>
    <button onClick={e => setCount(count + 1)} children={count} />
    <time ref={dateRef}>0</time>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```css
body::before { content: "render only triggers when state changes" }
button::before { content: "click:" }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is a really nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is you need to NOT call `setCurrentTime` on every event.

More practically you can either use some custom logic to define which events to skip. Or you can use generic helper functions to do so. If you want your function to not be called more often than every N ms it is call `throttle`. You can use lodash or other utility libraries for that

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle

Live example https://laracasts.com/series/build-modern-laravel-apps-using-inertia-js/episodes/22

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if (wavesurferRef.current){
            wavesurferRef.current.on('audioprocess', throttle(function () {

                //ISSUE: THIS MAKE COMPONENT RE-RENDERING TOO MANY TIME
                setCurrentTime(wavesurferRef.current.getCurrentTime())
            })
        }, 1000); // fire only once a second
    },[])
```

Comment: I don't think this would work well in my case since I also have functionality to stop the audio, and when I run it again, the display time will be out of sync with the actual current time

Answer (score 0):

Since in my application, I only need the value in seconds, so I use this simple approach to `Math.floor` the value and `setState()`, cause `setState` only change the state if the value is different, therefore, the component will just be re-rendered every seconds.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   if (wavesurferRef.current){
       wavesurferRef.current.on('audioprocess', function () {
           setCurrentTime(Math.floor(wavesurferRef.current.getCurrentTime()))
       })
   }
},[])
```